# Clicking reliably random link in python selenium phantomjs

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm using this function in python to select random link from current opened page and click on it:

```
def click_random_link(driver):
  print("Clicking random link ")
  links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@href]")
  if len(links):
    l = links[randint(0, len(links) - 1)]
    print(l.get_attribute("href"))
    sleep(1)
    l.click()
    return True
  else:
    print('Link NOT found....')
    return False
```

Seems simple enough, but its very very unreliable.. in more than 80% time I will get

```
errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated"
```

No matter what I try in phantomjs I can'g get it to reliably click on link.. I have tried to maxime window, tried focusing the link, nothing works :( One last shot to dark here, but even almighty google had no answers...

Comment: Have you tried scrolling the link into view after locating the element by xpath? Oftentimes, I have found that an advertisement / header / footer can hover over the link you are trying to click

Comment: I have tried adding this to focus the link but the results are mostly the same, its not 100% reliable.

`action = ActionChains(driver)
 action.move_to_element(l).click().perform()`

Comment: Looks like I will have to take that back :D, running test now and so far so good with the move_to_element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all links fetched by your selector are visible- some of them might be located, for example, inside hidden `div`, so you cannot handle them even with `action.move_to_element(l)`...

To handle only visible links you can try below code:

```
def click_random_link(driver):
    print("Clicking random link ")
    links = [link for link in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a") if link.is_displayed()]
    if links:
        l = links[randint(0, len(links) - 1)]
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', l)
        print(l.get_attribute("href"))
        sleep(1)
        l.click()
    else:
        print('Link NOT found....')
```

Comment: Interesting, I will give it a try and report back :)

Comment: Ends in error:
   `driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', link)
NameError: name 'link' is not defined`

should be:
`driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', l)`

This works, still some issue exists :D not with your code, that seems to work.. but it trys to click on `javascript:vote(272507,1292405,'neg');` which is link on page I guess :D need to figure out how to remove java scripts from the links and keep only proper links

Comment: You are right I have edited the comment above, as you were typing :D